# Issue with loading user class

Tags: php

I have a small problem with the following php code. On the input for the name, I'm trying to show their current username, by `$user->username`, only it gives me the following error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: user in /home/**/domains/**/public_html/dev/edit_account.php on line 36
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/**/domains/**/public_html/dev/edit_account.php on line 36

in the game_header.php file I have

```
$user = new User($_SESSION['id']);
```

And thought it would work, but sadly it does not.

I have also tried

```
$user = new User($_SESSION['id']);
```

on the edit_account.php page, but I was getting the same error.

Here's the edit_account.php code.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong here?

```
    include "game_header.php";

    $_GET['type'] = isset($_GET['type']) && ctype_alpha($_GET['type']) ? trim($_GET['type']) : '0';

switch($_GET['type']) {
    case 'profileoptions' : profile_options(); break;
    default : profile_options();
}

function profile_options() {
    echo '
      
    ';
    include 'game_footer.php';
}
```

Comment: `session_start();` I don't see it anywhere. Is it in all the pages or did you leave it out?

Comment: @Fred the session_start(); is in the game_header.php at the top of the file.

Comment: It must be in `all` files that are being used, general rule of thumb. May be "part" of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When encased into a function you must do the following:

```
global $user ; //Bring a global variable to the current scope.
echo $user->username ; //Then you can access it and its properties.
```

So it must start with:

```
function profile_options() {
  global $user ;
  //The rest of code
}
```

However, I recommend you to create a parameter:

```
function profile_options(User $user){
  //Much code
}
```

Then call it where `$user` is accessible:

```
profile_options($user) ;
```

Comment: Thank you, that pretty much did the job. Thanks alot!